# Git Switch vs Checkout in Netbeans

Tags: git

I'm still struggling with Git.

The thing is:

We're a two persons working on a project.

I created a new branch out of master called relation.

Now my friend have updated master but needs me to fix some bugs on it.

When I do a switch to branch in Netbeans it gives me all my "relation"-changes and wants me to commit them.

That's not what I'm looking for!

Netbeans site tells me this [Switch to branch]:

```
Switch to Branch
Actor: User

Action: User wants to switch to a branch (see also Checkout)

"Priority:" 1

Scenario:

User selects a versioned context and invokes 'switch branch' from the main menu
User specifies the branch and additional options - keep local changes etc.
The working tree is switched to the specified branch
```

and [Checkout]:

Checkout

```
Actor: User

Action: User wants to checkout a specific revision/tag/branch

"Priority:" 1

Scenario:

User selects a a versioned context and invokes 'chekout' from the main menu
User specifies the revision/tag/branch to checkout
The working tree will be switched to the specified revision
```

I'm getting a headache from GIT!

So what's the difference between theese two?

I need to someone be able to switch to the [Master] branch and then update the bugs, and then switch back to my [Relation] branch without git telling me to commit changes from [Relation] when I'm on the [Master] branch

Comment: is it more clear now?

Comment: So, "git switch" is not a git operation, that must be some Netbeans git terminology.

Comment: I haven't touched at netbeans but what you are looking for is the equivalent of `git stash` followed by a `git checkout`. The switch of Netbeans seems to try to pop the local changes on top of the newly checked out branch -- avoid that

Comment: Sounds like they want to switch branches without committing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The difference between "Swtich Branch" and "Checkout" is the nature of what you can checkout:

- "Switch Branch": you checkout only a branch
- "[Checkout](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout)": you checkout any `<tree-ish>` reference (i.e. commit, tag or tree)

While still on `relation`, you need to:

- either [Add](https://netbeans.org/projects/versioncontrol/pages/Git_uc#Add) then [commit](https://netbeans.org/projects/versioncontrol/pages/Git_uc#Commit) your current modification
- or [stash](https://netbeans.org/projects/versioncontrol/pages/Git_func#Stash) your current non-committed modification

Then, with a clear working tree, you can [switch branch](https://netbeans.org/projects/versioncontrol/pages/Git_uc#Switch_to_Branch).

See the [Netbeans User Guide on Checkout](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/git.html#branchCheckOut)

> **Note**: If you want to switch your files to a branch that already exists (e.g., to a commit that is not at the top of one of your branches), you can:
>
> - use the `Team > Git > Branch > Switch To Branch` command,
> - specify the branch in the `Switch to Selected Branch` dialog box,
> - check it out as a new branch (optionally),
> - and press Switch.

Comment: What do you mean by ""Checkout": you checkout any <tree-ish> reference (i.e. commit, tag or tree)"

Comment: @MaggiQall I mean that, contrary to "Switch to Branch", you can checkout other references than just a branch. You can checkout a commit or a tag (which  you cannot do with "Switch to Branch", where you checkout *only* a branch). Of course, checkout a commit or a tag would leave you in a DETACHED HEAD mode (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965676/why-did-git-detach-my-head/3965714#3965714). So in your case, "Switch to Branch" is safer.